# Hours between two times within a select?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to calculate number of hours between the start of the PID and the current time, as part of a select, as an expression.  I'm trying something like this, but it comes back as empty.  I've been staring at this for 2 hours and can't get anywhere.

Help greatly appreciated.

```
$Now = Get-date
$StartTime= @{n='StartTime';e={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.CreationDate)}}

$serverlist = invoke-sqlcmd -serverinstance sqlservername -database myrepodb `
-query "SELECT server FROM dbo.ServerList" 

$serverlist|%{
    $computer = $_.server

    gwmi win32_process -cn $_.server -filter "Name='notepad.exe' `
       AND CreationDate IS NOT NULL" | 
    select @{Name = 'Servername'; Expression = {"$computer"}},$StartTime, processid, `
    @{Name = 'HoursDiff'; Expression = {([datetime]$Now - [datetime]$_.CreationDate)}}
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure there are computers in `$serverlist`?  The gwmi call works for me against localhost.  Have you tried just `localhost` to see if the problem is in the Win32_Process query or if it is in your invoke-sqlcmd call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that it is `HoursDiff` that comes back empty, the issue appears to be with the conversion of WMI DMTF dates into PowerShell (.NET) datetimes. Replace `$_.ConvertToDateTime` and `[datetime]$_.CreationDate` with calls to [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementdatetimeconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). For example:

```
[System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($_.CreationDate)
```

Comment: Aha!  Okay, that gets me so that I get back (if up for 13 hours and 15 minutes and change) 13:15:22.8509847 . Using that and finishing off the subtraction with ".TotalHours" does it!  Many thanks, sir!